# AWS::S3 write object that has key with slash characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, filesystems

This may apply to general file-system as well.

In my case I want to write files on Aws-S3 where the key(filename) is actually a url path.

**For example :**

```
url = "http://example.com/where/are/we/"
```

then filename would be

```
filename = "where/are/we/"
```

**To write in S3 :**

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
s3.buckets[BUCKET].objects["locations/#{filename}"].write(file_contents)
```

But as expected the key creates sub-folders inside `BUCKET/locations/where/are/we/`

My last resort would be `filename.gsub!('/', '_')`

Any possible solution/workaround would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I settled with `filename.gsub!('/', '_')`. As we can't have slash in filename.

Answer (score 4):

S3 keys are keys, not folders or filenames. But a lot of tools handle them like folders and files (what makes perfectly sense IMHO). Since everybody comes up with the analogy of folders and files, I would treat keys like folders and files. That means: Do not use slashes in keys.

Another approach might be to just add a filename that makes sense in your context. For example, if you store web-ish content in your bucket under such a key, store them under `where/are/we/index.html` instead of just `where/are/we/`.

Comment: Yes thats right I do store 'web-ish' content but as a JSON and I want to name the file same as the path. It seems that would break the filesystem analogy, so I `gsub('/', '_')`.

Comment: wanted to add that S3 Keys cannot start with slashes so where/are/we/index.html is valid key and /where/are/we/index.html is not (I got caught out by it)