# Amazon S3 client could not download file with spaces or hash?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am using `AWSSDK.S3` version `3.3.17.2` and `AWSSDK.Core` version `3.3.21.16` to upload a file and then download the same file. The code below not able to download the file **if the file name has spaces ( or `#`)**

```
public class AmazonS3
{
    public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(string sourceFile, string s3BucketUrl)
    {
        AmazonS3Uri s3Uri = new AmazonS3Uri(s3BucketUrl);
        using (var s3 = new AmazonS3Client(s3Uri.Region))
        {
            using (TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(s3))
            {
                TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = s3Uri.Bucket,
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    FilePath = sourceFile,
                    Key = s3Uri.Key + Path.GetFileName(sourceFile),
                };

                await utility.UploadAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        return Path.Combine(s3BucketUrl, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile));
    }  

    public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string destinationFilePath, string s3Url)
    {
        var s3Uri = new AmazonS3Uri(s3Url);
        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(s3Uri.Region);
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = s3Uri.Bucket,
            Key = s3Uri.Key
        };

        // dispose the underline stream when writing to local file system is done
        using (var getObjectResponse = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            await getObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(destinationFilePath, false, default(System.Threading.CancellationToken)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }              
}
```

Then for testing purpose i am uploading the file and downloading the same file again

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3();

var uploadedFileS3Link = await s3.UploadFileAsync("C:\\temp\\my test file.pdf", @"https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/test/");

// get exception at line below
await s3.DownloadFileAsync("C:\\temp\\downloaded file.pdf",uploadedFileS3Link );
```

I am getting exception

> **Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist**. --->
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server
>   returned an error: **(404) Not Found**. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.     at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)  --- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---     at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)     at ......

*removed remaining exception for brevity*

The file does exist inside bucket. In-fact i can copy and paste the s3url (i.e. the value of `uploadedFileS3Link` variable)  and download the file via browser.

(Note that in reality i am trying to download 1000+ files that are already uploaded with spaces in their name. So removing the spaces while uploading is not an option)

**Update 1**
i noticed S3 browser Url Encode the file name

[image]

I tried downloading the file using the encoded file path `https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/development/test/my%20test%20file.pdf`
 but it still did not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so finally i found what was the issue. I am using [AmazonS3Uri](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/edit/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Util/AmazonS3Uri.cs) class to parse the given S3 url and get the key, bucket and region. The `AmazonS3Uri`  returns my key as `development/test/my%20test%20file.pdf`

Because internally `AmazonS3Uri` is using `System.Uri` to build Uri and then returns `AbsolutePath` which returns Encoded path as Key (*Should it return Local Path as Key?*)

I don't know why but `AmazonS3Client` does not like it, and it throws exception if you pass Encoded key.

So to fix the issue i decode the key using `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(s3Uri.Key)`. So new download method looks like

```
    public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string destinationFilePath, string s3Url)
    {
        var s3Uri = new S3UrlParser(s3Url);
        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(s3Uri.Region);
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = s3Uri.Bucket,
            Key = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(s3Uri.Key)
        };

        // dispose the underline stream when writing to local file system is done
        using (var getObjectResponse = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            await getObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(destinationFilePath, false, default(System.Threading.CancellationToken)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue parsing filename with space and forward slashes in the name. The problem with unescaped forward slashes is most tools treat each forward slash as a directory delimiter within S3.

So a simple name like myfilename = "file/name.pdf" appended to a virtual path would turn into; "directory/subdirectory/myfile/name.pdf" (here it will now have a directory called myfile where it was not intended)

It can be mitigated by escaping the filename "directory/subdirectory/myfile%2fname.pdf" at the point of upload and then decoding as suggested in the answer of this post.

After a experiencing errors from erroneous slashes and blank folder names in AWS Explorer caused by extra double slashes e.g. "//" (described further here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120135)

I've come to the conclusion it's better to completely strip forward slashes altogether from any filename proportion (not the virtual directory) rather than relying on escaping on upload and unescaping it on download. Treating the forward slash as a reserved character as others have similarly experienced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19515741/1165173

In the case of an escaped whitespace symbol "+" it is usually safe to unescape the character and it will work as intended.

Filename proportion can be encoded using

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.Encode(input);
```

List of non-acceptable filename characters can be compared at the point of file creation using Path.GetInvalidPathChars()

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars